# Symfony2 Sylius e-commerce check for routes

Tags: symfony, routes, e-commerce, sylius

I am working with Sylius e-commerce (Symfony 2), and I want to know is it possible to check is my route accessed.
For example if I have 3 kind of routes :

../aboutus.. /home.. /contact

and how I could check if my /home is accessed so I can do some actions about that.

Thanks,
Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that I've found solution to this, in a twig.template you can do this:

{{ app.request.get('_route') }}

that returns path of accessed route